# Is it possible to use the load line analysis technique on two diodes?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

I understand the load line analysis is a way of solving two equations. In the two diodes case, I also have two equations.

In number 5 for example, I will try to get the VD1 using the load line method.

1) 5 = - VD1 - VD2

Id2 = Is2 * ( exp( VD2 / (2*VT) ) - 1)

VD2 = 2 * VT * ln(Id2 / Is2 + 1)

Id1 = Id2 because the diodes are in series

So Equation 1 is 5 = -VD1 - 2 * VT * ln (Id1 / Is2 + 1)

2) Eqaution 2 is Id1 = Is1 * ( exp(VD1 / (2 * VT)) - 1)

So now I have two equations in VD1 and Id1, But my calculator can not solve them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

load line analysis works fine for voltage dividers, graphically.

And works fine for diodes in series with resistors.

And works for transistor/tubes and a series load resistor.